# How to insert multiple values into one column?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I'm setting up a database for a game server and I'm new to databases, I've encountered a problem where I have to insert **multiple players** into the **same column**, basically I have a group and in that group I need to insert multiple players, so I have these columns at the moment:

```
Group Name:
Group Owner:
Players:
Creation Date:
```

How would I go about adding **multiple** players into a group? Would I need to just insert **all of them** into the **same column** and use ***String.split()*** in Java?
Or is there a **better way** of doing this?

Comment: You don't want to insert serialized datas in DB. This goes against the purpose of using a RDBMS. Think about [DB Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: You could have another table of `Player` (or some specific 'role' on your `Person` table to indicate that they're players), and then either have an array of `BIG INT`s in your Players column (to indicate the player IDs for those players), or have _another_ table for `PlayerGroupMappings` which details GroupID and PlayerID (and the presence of an entry indicates there is a mapping there).

Comment: @Cid from what I understand DB Normalization, is basically having one more table that has 2 things in it - the values you need and a number which the number is the PK of your original table, so like how I can approach this is basically have another table full of players names/identifiers, and have another column which specifies which group they're related to?

Comment: @Coper please read [Ashley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59826307/8398549)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you are setting up a relational DB. To be blunt, you don't want to insert multiple values into one column. You want to design your tables based on the data and their *relationships* to each other. Right now, you seem to have two entities: Groups and Players. The relationship beween these two is that a Player can belong to a Group, correct? So then, you want to have a table for each entity and link them based on a key that represents their relationship:

```
Group:
 - group id (PRIMARY KEY)
 - name
 - owner
 - creation date

Player:
 - player id (PRIMARY KEY)
 - (any other player info you may need, like a name)
 - group id (FOREIGN KEY)
```

A *primary key* is a unique identifier for your table - it identifies one and only one entry. A *foreign key* references one and only one entry in another table (in this case, Group). The above design works **if players can belong to one and only one group**. If players can belong to multiple groups, you need another table to represent this relationship:

```
Group:
 - group id (PRIMARY KEY)
 - name
 - owner
 - creation date

Player:
 - player id (PRIMARY KEY)
 - (any other player info you may need, like a name)

PlayerGroup:
 - player id (FOREIGN KEY)
 - group id (FOREIGN KEY)
```

This design is now *relational* and *normalized*. You can get the data in your original design (or near to it) via queries (especially with joins). Maybe this explains a little better: https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html

Comment: Great example   !

Comment: Thank you for this very elaborate explanation! I don't know if I understood how the 2nd relationship make players able to join multiple groups, I understand that there are 2 columns - player id and group id, but would you need to assign the player multiple times to that table in order to have him in multiple groups? Just asking to see if I understood right.

Comment: So for every group that your player is in you would put an entry into PlayerGroup (and each entry in PlayerGroup is unique - it's a unique pair of a group_id and a player_id). So if you queried PlayerGroup by group_id you would get a list of all players in that group, and if you queried PlayerGroup by player_id you would get a list of all groups that that player belongs to.

Comment: Okay it's what I thought it is. Thank you so much! you helped a ton!

Comment: @Coper note that the primary key of the table `PlayerGroup` would be the combination of both foreign keys (AKA Composite key) This will ensure that a player won't be in 2 groups, because the combination `player_id, group_id` will be unique.

Comment: Doesn't having the PlayerGroup mean I can assign the player to multiple groups? Well I can check if the player exists in PlayerGroup but wouldn't it lose the whole purpose of this table? Wouldn't I rather make it like the first one if I only want the player to join 1 group?

Comment: I think @Cid meant that "this will ensure that a player won't be in the same group twice, because the combination is unique".

Comment: @Coper this means that if you add the player `4` in the group `2`, you'll obtain the comination `4, 2` if later you want again to add the player `4` in the group `2`, you can't, because the primary key `4, 2` already exists (But you are allowed to add the player `2` in the group `4`, the combination `4, 2` is different than the combination `2, 4`)

Comment: @Ashley indeed, after re-reading, I noticed my phrasing wasn't clear enough

Answer (score 0):

If possible to redesign the DB I would suggest to normalize it a bit and not store everything in a single table. For example you could have :
A Player table, storing all players (ef First/Last name, a unique ID etc)
Then a Group table storing Group Name , owner , creation date and a unique group ID.
And finally a table with Player & Group links that would store the player ID and the group ID for each Player<>Group relationship.

From such structure you can easily get any info you want via SQL (eg from java).
For example to get all players for a given group :

```
select p.player_name from Player_table p
join Player_Group_table pg on p.player_ID = pg.player_ID
join Group_table g on pg.group_ID = g.group_ID
where g.group_name = 'Your Group Name'
```